# How do I get the mailbox and the name of all of the participants of an appointement?

Tags: web-services, exchange-server

I am working with an Exchange web service, and I want to get the mailbox and the name of all the participants of an `appointment`.

I do this using:

```
foreach (Attendee participant in appointment.RequiredAttendees)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Attendee {0}", participant.Name);
}
```

and it returns me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

RequiredAttendees is a string. You need the Recipients collection.